# How to remove all files in a directory except one file in Solaris

Tags: shell-script, solaris

I have a directory icontaining a large number of files. I want to delete all files except for file.txt in Solaris. How do I do this?

I tried doing -->  rm !(UsageRequest.csv)

But it didn't worked. Solaris is throwing error as "Unexpected Token - '('  ".

Comment: That script runs perfectly for Unix but not for Solaris

Comment: @Amar Kumar The solution using `find`?

Comment: did you `shopt -s extglob` before `rm !(file.txt) ` ? this work on a solaris 10.

Comment: I have Solaris 5

Comment: @AmarKumar I doubt it, see /etc/release

Comment: I'm unable to access that as it is a restricted server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`!(UsageRequest.csv)` is a `ksh` globbing operator, it only works with `ksh` (also with `zsh -o kshglob` or `bash -O extglob`, but those shells don't come by default on Solaris).

So you need to run those commands in `ksh`. Note that the `/bin/sh` of  Solaris 11 is now based on ksh93, so it would work there, but you still shouldn't use those non-standard extensions in `sh` scripts there.

On Solaris 10 and earlier, `/bin/sh` is a Bourne shell. The standard `sh` is to be found elsewhere in `/usr/xpg4/bin/sh`. That `sh` is based on `ksh88`. Again `!(x)` would work there, but shouldn't be used there.

So, use:

```
#! /usr/bin/ksh -
rm -- !(UsageRequest.csv)
```

Or:

```
#! /usr/xpg4/bin/sh -
ksh -c 'rm -- !(UsageRequest.csv)'
```

POSIX (or Bourne) globs don't have negation operators. You'd need to do cumbersome things like:

```
set -- *
for i do
  [ UsageRequest.csv = "$i" ] || set -- "$@" "$i"
  shift
done
rm -- "$@"
```

Or you could use `find`:

```
find . ! -name . -prune ! -name '.*' ! -name 'UsageRequest.csv' \
  -exec rm -f {} +
```